# How to set keyboard focus to a textbox inside a user control in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, focusmanager

When I open the window *MyWindow*, I want to have the cursor of my keyboard pointing to the textbox contained in a user control that is contained in the window.

Usually, you would set `FocusManager.FocusedElement={Binding ElementName=TextBoxToPutFocusOn}`.

But here, my constraint is that **the textbox is inside a user control that is inside my window**.

How can my window set focus to this textbox?

To illustrate, here are my 2 files:

*MyWindow.xaml*

```
<Window
xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:MyWPFNamespace">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Sample text</TextBlock>
        <wpf:SpecialTextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*SpecialTextBox.xaml*

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyWPFNamespace.SpecialTextBox"
    x:Name="SpecialName">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxToPutFocusOn" />
</UserControl>
```

Thank you

Comment: try UIElement.Focus()

Comment: Why don't you override OnGotFocus in the code behind of the UserControl and call FocusManager.SetFocusedElement method?

Comment: Thank you @emoacht.
I am using WPF and not Windows Forms.
It seems OnGotFocus can be overriden if it is a WinForm control, right?

Comment: In WPF, I did it by setting the following property in the User Control: `FocusManager.GotFocus="MyTextBox_OnGotFocus"`

And in the code behind:
        `Private Sub TextBoxWithHint_OnGotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            MyTextBox.Focus()
        End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

WPF's UserControl inherits FrameworkElement which has [FrameworkElement.OnGotFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.ongotfocus) method. So you can use it as follows:

```cs
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);

    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(Window.GetWindow(this), this.TextBoxToPutFocusOn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by setting the following property in the User Control:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyWPFNamespace.SpecialTextBox"
    x:Name="SpecialName"
    FocusManager.GotFocus="MyTextBox_OnGotFocus">'
```

And in the code behind:

```
Private Sub TextBoxWithHint_OnGotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MyTextBox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Finally, in *MainWindow.xaml*:

```
<Window
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding SpecialName}">
```